# ASP.NET - Using Partial Views to Asynchronously Display Search Results Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I would like to have a table in my application that returns the results of a search. I have two UI components that assist in this. One, a text input that serves as the search string and two, a search by drop down menu that ultimately determines what database table to query.

My controller is set up as an HttpGet to accept parameters `searchBy` and `searchString` If search by is "option1" then it queries "table 1" if searchBy is "option2" it queries "Table2". I would like to then return a partial view to the main view without a refresh. I currently have this set up to where I have two different models and two different partial views that go with each other respectively. The plan is to use AJAX to send a "GET" tot the controller action with the appropriate parameters.

How do I use razor syntax in the main view so that it can handle either partial view being returned?

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Table(string searchBy, string searchString)
    {

        switch (searchBy)
        {
            case "Option 1":
                List<model1> Model1 = new List<model1>();
                var blah = from a in db.Table1 a;
                blah = blah.Where(a => a.propA.Contains(searchString)
                                   || a.propB.Contains(searchString));

                foreach (var a in blah)
                {
                    Model1.Add(new model1 {...... });
                }

                return PartialView("_PartialView1", Model1);

            case "Option2":
                List<model2> Model2 = new List<model2>();
                var foo = from p in db.Table2 select p;
                foo = foo.Where(p => p.propC.Contains(searchString)
                                  || p.propD.Contains(searchString)
                                  || p.propE.Contains(searchString)

                foreach (var p in foo)
                {
                    Model2.Add(new mode2 { .... });
                }

                return PartialView("_PartialView2", Model2);

            default:
                return PartialView("_DefaultPartialView");

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making an AJAX call, your main view won't have any Razor syntax to output your partial view. Your AJAX call will just return a bunch of rendered HTML (a long string - your Partial merged with your Model) that you just need to dump somewhere on your page.

So to answer your question *How do I use razor syntax in the main view so that it can handle either partial view being returned?* You won't use Razor for this task.

You will be making a call to your controller action via JavaScript, and that call will return HTML that you will dump in a predefined area.

Using jQuery it might look like this:

JavaScript:

```
$.get('/Home/Table', { searchBy : 'Option 1', searchString : 'test' }, function(partialView) {
    $('#output').html(partialView);
});
```

Main View:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```